Asking for feedback and contribution on post-quantum cryptography research project
my colleagues and I at Darmstadt University of Applied Sciences developed a public website with the goal of presenting all known scientific papers that add to the Post-Quantum Cryptography research. You can visit it under the link:
https://cspub.h-da.io/cma/

We would very much appreciate your contribution, participation and feedback to the current status of the website and the general idea. Our goal is to have a central, regularly used accesspoint for the entire community to discuss and present the ongoing research of all aspects of the expected migration to Post-Quantum Cryptography and cryptographic agility.
Have a great day!

I have migrated this promotion for a potentially useful site to our meta site as it does not constitute an answerable question about cryptography itself. The guidance for this is documented here while technically about events still feels applicable here.

Is this "how to contribute" only for Uni of Darmstadt members? In the PQC implementation section you could add Bouncy Castle; they have had a PQC section in the lightweight API + Java "provider" (plugable engine) for a long time. I don't know how up to date it is though. It must be relatively up to date with Sphinx, LMS, XMSS HBS algorithms as well as things like McEliece and NTRU. No things like CRYSTALS / Kyber & Dilithium though (see the package org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto on this page).

@MaartenBodewes
Thanks for your advice! So far you can submit contributions only via the mail address that you can find on the website.

Best structured overview, I have ever seen on this range of topics. Current state of the technology suggests it could take centuries to have a Quantum Computer with some 10000 Qubit working properly, so scalable conventional algorithms could escape attacks for long time. Does "crypto-agility" also consider this transition time to PQC or does it exclusively refer to certain classes of algorithms?
